# Rectangle bounds of isometric object to isometric bounds

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, 2d, 2d-graphics

This might sound confusing, but this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Cartesian bounds of isometric object]

project to:

[image: Isometric bounds of isometric object]

I already have an algorithm in my mind, where we simply detect the corners touching the Cartesian rectangle and calculate the bounds from there, but I just wanted to see if there were more clever ways of solving this problem.

**Note**

- It's not a homework
- I don't want a full answer, just a pointer, wondering if there are more clever ways of solving it.
- The isometric object can be a rectangle, it's width and height might differ.

Comment: Wouldn't the cartesian bounds of the rectangle with h=1 and w=2 be equal to the bounds of the rectangle with h=2 and w=1?

Comment: @ratchetfreak h=2 and w=1 on isometric space?

If so, I think not, the image that I posted has the same w and h on isometric space with 2:1 Cartesian bounds, but we could fit different objects with different isometric dimensions on the same Cartesian bounds.

Comment: Thinking again, my algorithm should take circles into account.